Is there a naming map for the Pathfinder 2e remaster?
As part of the remaster, Pathfinder 2e has renamed many spells and magic items, for example magic missile is now called force barrage, baleful polymorph is now cursed metamorphosis and hat of disguise is now masquerade scarf. Often there are also
minor functional changes.
Thankfully, it is possible to search for the legacy name on Archives of Nethys, and find out this way what the new name is. I can understand why doing this may desirable from a branding perspective for the game that mechanically has diverged quite a bit from being a D&D 3.5 continuation.
However, not all spell names changed. For example, invisibility is still just invisibility, with changes only to the spell description.
Is there a list somewhere, that provides an overview over the old and new names for all those spells and magic items that did change their names?

It's worth noting the main reason for renaming things is that newer books don't have the OGL allowing use of D&D content like spells and creatures (because WotC tried to revoke it), with Paizo using the new ORC license going forward.

Corporate scheming may be worth noting in general but it doesn't really help answer the question.

The Foundry VTT GitHub page for pf2e has a list of renamed terms in the wiki tab under "Remaster Changes"
This page has all changes (as of January 11, 2024) but here are the spells in case of link rot:



Spell Name
Status
New Name




Animate Dead
Renamed
summon undead


Augment Summoning
Renamed
Fortify Summoning


Baleful Polymorph
Renamed
cursed metamorphosis


Barkskin
Renamed
oaken resilience


Bind Soul
Renamed
seize soul


Blind Ambition
Renamed
Ignite Ambition


Blink
Renamed
Flicker


Burning Hands
Renamed
breathe fire


Calm Emotions
Renamed
calm


Charming Words
Renamed
Charming Push


Chill Touch
Renamed
Void Warp


Cloudkill
Renamed
toxic cloud


Color Spray
Renamed
dizzying colors


Commune with Nature
Merged
Commune


Comprehend Language
Renamed
translate


Continual Flame
Renamed
everlight


Crushing Despair
Renamed
wave of despair


Dancing Lights
Merged
Light


Dimension Door
Renamed
translocate


Dimensional Anchor
Renamed
planar seal


Dimensional Lock
Renamed
Planar Tether


Discern Location
Renamed
pinpoint


Disrupt Undead
Renamed
Vitality Lash


Disrupting Weapons
Renamed
Infuse Vitality


Endure Elements
Renamed
environmental endurance


Entangle
Renamed
entangling flora


False Life
Renamed
false vitality


Feather Fall
Renamed
gentle landing


Feeblemind
Renamed
Never Mind


Finger of Death
Renamed
execute


Flaming Sphere
Renamed
floating flame


Flesh To Stone
Renamed
petrify


Freedom of Movement
Renamed
unfettered movement


Gaseous Form
Renamed
vapor form


Gentle Repose
Renamed
peaceful rest


Glibness
Renamed
honeyed words


Glitterdust
Merged
revealing light


Globe of Invulnerability
Renamed
Dispelling Globe


Hallucinatory Terrain
Renamed
mirage


Hideous Laughter
Renamed
laughing fit


Horrid Wilting
Renamed
desiccate


Hypnotic Pattern
Renamed
hypnotize


Inspire Competence
Renamed
uplifting overture


Inspire Courage
Renamed
courageous anthem


Inspire Defense
Renamed
rallying anthem


Inspire Heroics
Renamed
fortissimo composition


Know Direction
Renamed
know the way


Legend Lore
Renamed
collective memories


Longstrider
Renamed
tailwind


Mage Armor
Renamed
mystic armor


Mage Hand
Renamed
telekinetic hand


Magic Aura
Renamed
disguise magic


Magic Fang
Renamed
runic body


Magic Missile
Renamed
force barrage


Magic Mouth
Renamed
embed message


Magic Weapon
Renamed
runic weapon


Magnificent Mansion
Renamed
planar palace


Maze
Renamed
quandary


Meld into Stone
Renamed
one with stone


Meteor Swarm
Renamed
falling stars


Mind Blank
Renamed
Hidden Mind


Misdirection
Renamed
disguise magic


Modify Memory
Renamed
rewrite memory


Neutralize Poison
Renamed
cleanse affliction


Nondetection
Renamed
veil of privacy


Obscuring Mist
Renamed
mist


Pass Without Trace
Renamed
Vanishing Tracks


Passwall
Renamed
Magic Passage


Phantom Mount
Renamed
Marvelous mount


Planar Binding
Renamed
planar servitor


Plane Shift
Renamed
interplanar teleport


Positive Luminance
Renamed
Vital Luminance


Private Sanctum
Renamed
peaceful bubble


Prying Eye
Renamed
scouting eye


Pulse of The City
Renamed
Pulse of Civilization


Purify Food And Drink
Renamed
cleanse cuisine


Ray of Enfeeblement
Renamed
Enfeeble


Remove Curse
Renamed
cleanse affliction


Remove Disease
Renamed
cleanse affliction


Remove Fear
Renamed
clear mind


Remove Paralysis
Renamed
sure footing


Restore Senses
Renamed
Sound Body


Scorching Ray
Renamed
blazing bolt


Searing Light
Renamed
holy light


See Invisibility
Renamed
see the unseen


Shadow Walk
Renamed
umbral journey


Shapechange
Renamed
metamorphosis


Shield Other
Renamed
share life


Sound Burst
Renamed
noise blast


Spectral Hand
Renamed
ghostly carrier


Spider Climb
Renamed
gecko grip


Splash of Art
Renamed
Creative Splash


Stone Tell
Renamed
speak with stones


Stoneskin
Renamed
mountain resilience


Tanglefoot
Renamed
tangle vine


Time Stop
Renamed
freeze time


Tongues
Renamed
truespeech


Touch of Idiocy
Renamed
stupefy


Tree Shape
Renamed
one with plants


Tree Stride
Renamed
nature's pathway


Trueseeing
Renamed
truesight


True Strike
Renamed
sure strike


Unseen Servant
Renamed
phantasmal minion


Vampiric Touch
Renamed
vampiric feast


Veil
Merged
Illusory Disguise


Vigilant Eye
Renamed
Rune of Observation


Wail of the Banshee
Renamed
Wails of the Damned


Wind Walk
Renamed
Migration


Zone of Truth
Renamed
Ring of Truth




This is a good starting point but arguably not a complete list. While this covers those elements that were purely renamed (I think), it does not include, for example, any of the spells that, along with being renamed, were reworked, such as Produce Flame becoming Ignition and losing its Stat modifier to damage in favor of an extra die, or Ray of Frost getting the same treatment, and being changed to a fort save from an attack roll while being renamed Frostbite. (Cot’d…)

… while it is true that the PFS and general official guidance is that “if the name and mechanics have changed, both spells are valid, for those that prefer the legacy versions” - primarily as a bone thrown to Magus players and others inadvertently nerfed by the changes - you’ll find, for example, that archives of Nethys will redirect you from Shocking Grasp to Thunderstrike, and will not even show Shocking Grasp in spell lists unless you are exclusively looking through legacy content. So there are multiple ways to handle a map like this.

Yes, and in addition, neither AoN, Foundry, nor Pathbuilder are official Paizo sources, even though all of them have their own rulings on this.
The only real ruling we have, is the one you mentioned: "if the name and mechanics have changed, both spells are valid, for those that prefer the legacy versions". You're right about Frostbite and Shocking Grasp - both should still be valid according to Paizo, but both Pathbuilder and AoN consider them legacy.
One small addition: the removal of spellcasting ability mod as damage IS official, even for legacy cantrips. This was updated in errata
